# Несколько селекторов в одной файле Android

Tags: android

Всем привет. Есть шаблон кнопок

```
<Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector1"
        android:onClick="click_btn"
        android:id="@+id/add_artist"

        android:layout_margin="14dp"/>

<Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector2"
        android:onClick="click_btn"
        android:id="@+id/add_artist"

        android:layout_margin="14dp"/>
```

Так же есть два файле с selector

btn_selector_1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_1_s"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_item_1"/>
</selector>
```

и второй селектор такое же, только путь на картинку другой.
Так вот у меня планируется 4 кнопки, и если делать так же как и сейчас, то понадобится создать 4 файла селектора, для того что бы каждая кнопка менялась при нажатии. Можно ли реализовать эти действия в одном селекторе и как обращаться к такому селектору из шаблона?

Comment: Вы покажите хотя бы рисунки чем отличаются, вот тогда можно Вас сказать что делать. А то вопрос не понятень

Comment: в селекторе можно описать стиль для каждого состояния а не для элемента + его стояния, скорее всего это не реально. нет разницы дублирование кода в одном файле и дублирование кода в разных файлах)